# connecting an android app to a server and make it run a python program with input taken from the app?

Tags: android, python, json

The Android app I am supposed to develop takes only one integer as input. I have to implement the app in such a way that when a button is pressed, it needs to start an execution of the program in the server, then take an input from the user and send it to that process which is being executed. Then after the execution the server should return the output to the Android app. I would like to know any method to solve this problem. I have tried searching over the web but could not find good solutions to solve the problem.

Comment: You just need to be able to send requests to a server and get responses back. There are many tutorials on this. What have you tried searching for?

Comment: I have tried json implementation but i am struck  to send the command/request to server  and retrieve information back.

Comment: Show your code, and describe what's going wrong.  I'd have a look at this too if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was doing it all wrong like i was writing two StringRequest methods one for sending and one for receiving with get and post method with volley and encountered some errors and was not able to receive any thing from the server. My colleague helped me solve the issue by explaining how it is done and the corrections to be made. Thanks for giving the link for lookup for posting and stuff. Will do it from. The next time